# Codeigniter jquery cannot pass all the values from JS to the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

Just want to pass all the values from JS file to the view. Now it passes only one result. For example, I got values for **question 1, answer1, question 2, answer2** but it passes to the view the values **question2** and **answer2** only. Could you please help me to pass all the values from JS to the view using a loop in jquery.

Here is my view:

```
 <div id="accordion">
                 <h3><a href="#" class="question"></a></h3>
                 <div class="answer"></div>  
            </div>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Here is my JS file:

```
$(".faq_title").click(function(){
    var title = $(this).text();

    $.post('faq/get_faq_data', { title: title }, function (data) {

        var my_obj = data;        
        $.each(my_obj, function (i) {

           var question = my_obj[i].faq_question;
           var answer = my_obj[i].faq_answer;    

               $('.question').text(question);
               $('.answer').text(answer);      
         });        
        }, "json"); });
```

P.S.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `class` attribute to set the data to the `accordion` element which in you case only contains one element at first , only the last question-answer set is displayed as a result.

So you should try creating dynamic content for the accordion instead of single static element. So to begin with it create a blank accordion as :

```
<div id="accordion">
   <!--nothing at first!-->
</div>
```

and then you could set the question answer segment in accordion via jQuery :

```
  var my_obj = data;        
    $.each(my_obj, function (i) {
     var question = my_obj[i].faq_question;
     var answer = my_obj[i].faq_answer;
     //create new accordion element from the answer question set 
     var dynaContent = "<h3><a href='#' class='question'>'"+question+"'</a></h3><div class='answer'>'"+answer+"'</div>";
    //append it to the accordion container
    $("#accordion").append(dynaContent);
    });
    //refresh accordion
    $('#accordion').accordion("refresh");
```

This also work if you have a default element inside the accordion. Hope this help.

Here is a working [DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a6rCu/451/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. The problem is that I have several groups of questions and a title list on my view(please see the picture in my edited question). Each title corresponds to one question group. For example, if I click **title1**, _question1_ and _question2_ are loaded. When I click on **title2**, _question1_ and _question2_ should disappear and only after that _question3_ and _question4_ are loaded. In your example we append a new question group without disappearing the previous one. Could you check it please?

Comment: after the AJAX call success just use `$("#accordion").html("");` to clear out the previous question sets.